# Usage of "In present-day"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does the sentence

```
In present day technology, the method can be broadly applied.
```

correctly translate the idea that

```
Now, with the development of inexpensive desktop computers, the method can be broadly applied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud say: *With present-day technology, the method can be broadly applied*

Yes, the meaning is similar to the second sentence if you are implying a wider accessibility of technology to general public.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to say "present day", it should just be "present".  I would start the sentence - "With present technology..."

Comment: OK, I'll change accordingly